Viewport navigation center snapping to surface (like in CAD software) for simpler use of 3d mouse
I was using the 3D connexion space mouse for the first time within blender and was missing a critical navigation feature when comparing the 3D mouse behaviour to classical CAD software. In CAD the viewport navigation center (pivot) always snaps to the closest surface in the middle of the screen, making it far easier to navigate through more complex scenes.

As this feature was missing, I created a python script that emulates that exact behaviour. It works in three steps:
First it detects if the camera is currently moving. If the camera stops, it then defines a ray trace from the center of the viewport camera into the scene, looking for any surface to hit. If the trace hits a surface, the viewpoint center is then set to the trace hit, without actually moving the viewport camera, just moving the camera pivot.
Issues:
The script attaches itself to a handler and is then continuously ticking in the background, but currently it has to be manually started each time you boot up blender. There is also currently no way to stop the script from running (besides closing blender). Ideally this would be packed into some kind of addon, where this behaviour is either activated on blender startup or can be activated and deactivated with a button on a sidebar.
Below is the working code in the current format, I hope this helps for people searching for the same solution:
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

# Variables to store previous location and rotation of the viewport camera
previous_location = None
previous_rotation = None
camera_stopped = False

def check_viewport_camera_movement():
    global previous_location, previous_rotation, camera_stopped
    
    # Get the active 3D view region and the corresponding region_3d object (viewport camera data)
    area = next(area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D')
    region_3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d
    
    # Get the current location and rotation of the viewport camera
    current_location = region_3d.view_location
    current_rotation = region_3d.view_rotation
    
    # Check if this is the first time or if the camera moved
    if previous_location is None or previous_rotation is None:
        # Initialize previous values on the first run
        previous_location = current_location.copy()
        previous_rotation = current_rotation.copy()
        return 0.1  # Short delay for quick initial updates

    # Check if the camera's position or rotation has changed
    if current_location != previous_location or current_rotation != previous_rotation:
        # Camera is moving; reset stop flag and update previous values
        camera_stopped = False
        previous_location = current_location.copy()
        previous_rotation = current_rotation.copy()
        # print("Viewport camera is moving...")
    else:
        # Camera has not moved; check if it has stopped
        if not camera_stopped:
            camera_stopped = True
            # print("Viewport camera has stopped moving.")
            
            ###########  RAYTRACE FOR SURFACE ####################

            def raytrace_from_viewport_camera(threshold=1000):
                # Get the active 3D view region and the corresponding region_3d object (viewport camera data)
                area = next(area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D')
                region_3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d
                region_3d.update()
                
                #update scene
                context = bpy.context
                scene = context.scene
                context.view_layer.update()

                # Get the viewport's camera location and rotation from region_3d
                # Use region_3d to get the camera's view direction
                camera_rotation = region_3d.view_rotation
                camera_location = region_3d.view_location + ( camera_rotation @ Vector((0.0, 0.0, 1.0)) ) * region_3d.view_distance
                

                # Calculate the direction of the ray based on the camera rotation (forward direction)
                ray_direction = camera_rotation @ Vector((0.0, 0.0, -1.0))  # Forward direction in camera space

                # Add an offset to the start position to prevent starting the ray at the camera's exact location
                ray_start = camera_location + (ray_direction * 0.1)  # Small offset in the direction the camera is facing

                # Set the endpoint of the ray
                ray_end = ray_start + ray_direction * threshold

                # Perform the raycast
                hit, location, normal, index, object, matrix = bpy.context.scene.ray_cast(
                    bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph, ray_start, ray_end
                )

                # Check the result and print appropriate messages
                if hit:              
                    region_3d.view_distance = (camera_location - location).length
                    
                    region_3d.view_location = location
                    
            # Run the raytrace function
            raytrace_from_viewport_camera(threshold=5000)
            
            ######################################################
    
    # Continuously run this function with a short delay
    return 0.1

# Register the check function to run repeatedly
bpy.app.timers.register(check_viewport_camera_movement, first_interval=0.1)

If you want to try the script out yourself, open a text editor panel in blender, create a new blank script and paste the code. Then run the script either with the Run Script button or by pressing Alt + P
If you aren't sure about the effect of the script, I can recommend enabling the navigation guide in Edit > Preferences > Input > NDOF > Show Navigation Guide.
Feel free to modify the current code or pack it into an addon, I am curious what other people will do with it.
I also know this post is not a question and more a call to discussion, but the code itself was not enough for a full plugin I could upload on Blendermarket or similar sites. If there is a better platform to share this code and information, just let me know.
